# Beginner with nested array question -- adding values together

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
$products = array('Shoes' =>  array('price' => 49.99, 'shipping' => 5), 
                  'Shirt' =>  array('price' => 29.99, 'shipping' => 3),
                  'Socks'=>   array('price' => 2.99, 'shipping' => 0) 
                    );
```

I am having trouble traversing a multi-dimensional array and adding the elements.  Are there any tips for a PHP beginner?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the total price of all products, including shipping, you can calculate it without an explicit loop using [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
echo array_sum(array_map('array_sum', $products)); // prints 90.97
```

Note that `array_map` applies `array_sum` to each of the inner arrays, after which `array_sum` is finally applied to the result of this operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$price = 0;
foreach($products as $product) {
  $price += array_sum($product);
}
```

This has the advantage of being more readable than using `array_map`, but provides the same output.

Answer (score 0):

array_sum:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

rough sketch of code:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($products as $item => $amount_array){
   $total += array_sum($amount_array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$products = array('Shoes' =>  array('price' => 49.99, 'shipping' => 5), 
                  'Shirt' =>  array('price' => 29.99, 'shipping' => 3),
                  'Socks'=>   array('price' => 2.99, 'shipping' => 0) 
                    );

$total = 0;
foreach($products as $product)
{
    $total += $product["price"];
}

echo $total;
```

What you have is a variable called $product in each loop. That variable has in the first round "Shoes" as the key and the array as the value. So you can call it just as you would a normal array.